# UICollectionView Left align cells with dynamic widths

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

So I have a collection view like shown below:

```
       -----------              ----------------
      | some text |            | Some more text |
       -----------              ----------------
 -----------------------    -----------------------
| Some really Long text |  | Some longer text here |
 -----------------------    -----------------------
```

And I would like it to be:

```
 -----------                ----------------
| some text |              | Some more text |
 -----------                ----------------
 -----------------------    -----------------------
| Some really Long text |  | Some longer text here |
 -----------------------    -----------------------
```

I was able to get my cells to dynamically adjust their width to allow for a label to display its text, but I would like all of the cells to be left aligned with their section insets instead of being centered.

Edit:
I've tried a lot of things so far, but here is the last thing (doesn't actually work)

```
class LeftAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        let attributesForElementsInRect = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        var newAttributesForElementsInRect = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for attributes in attributesForElementsInRect! {
            let refAttributes = attributes
            refAttributes.frame.origin.x = self.sectionInset.left + 8
            newAttributesForElementsInRect.append(refAttributes)
        }

        return newAttributesForElementsInRect
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it would be easier to set the widths of each cell in a section equal to each other instead, that would force all of the cells in the section to aligned with each other instead of centering inside of the section. I'm not sure how to approach this though - the sizeForItemAt seems like palace to start, but I don't want to override auto layout setting the widths dynamically for the labels.

Comment: Show your layout code - what have you tried so far?

Comment: @creeperspeak I added my latest attempt to my original question

Comment: @Aaron you have to just align your collectionview to center instead of Left

Comment: @JitendraModi I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: just search collectionview cells alignment center